# Why is my CSS-delaration ignored?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to overwrite Bootstrap's padding for small screens because it creates too much space for what I want to achieve.
Chrome's Inspector shows me this:

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

(from bootstrap.css:1607).

If I remember correctly, more granular declarations would overwrite the general ones, so I thought I'll do a declaration for `div .col*`(embedded in a media-query for small screens):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div .col-lg-1, div .col-lg-10, div .col-lg-11, div .col-lg-12, div .col-lg-2, div .col-lg-3, div .col-lg-4, div .col-lg-5, div .col-lg-6, div .col-lg-7, div .col-lg-8, div .col-lg-9, div .col-md-1, div .col-md-10, div .col-md-11, div .col-md-12, div .col-md-2, div .col-md-3, div .col-md-4, div .col-md-5, div .col-md-6, div .col-md-7, div .col-md-8, div .col-md-9, div .col-sm-1, div .col-sm-10, div .col-sm-11, div .col-sm-12, div .col-sm-2, div .col-sm-3, div .col-sm-4, div .col-sm-5, div .col-sm-6, div .col-sm-7, div .col-sm-8, div .col-sm-9, div .col-xs-1, div .col-xs-10, div .col-xs-11, div .col-xs-12, div .col-xs-2, div .col-xs-3, div .col-xs-4, div .col-xs-5, div .col-xs-6, div .col-xs-7, div .col-xs-8, div .col-xs-9  {padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;}
}
```

The `head`loads Bootstrap.min.css first, then my .css-File. If I look at a `div`with the Inspector, the "Styles"-Tab still shows the bootstrap-declarations being applied, not mine. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** following the suggestions from Comments, I added !important - did not help. I verified that the .css-File is loaded and I chekced in Inspector's sources-Tab that exactly THAT file was active. So I [validated my CSS](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) and it turned out some poor tired dev (can't be me?!) had written comments with `//`instead of `/*` and that caused PARSER ERRORs!

Comment: Can you try adding! important to you css fields? If that does not work, maybe your css is not at all loaded? Can you paste the file name and the reference from your ts class?

Comment: What you could try is add `!important` to each of the styles.

Comment: It should work. But you shouldn't even need the div either. That said, I copied and pasted your code to test it, and it did work though, maybe there is an issue with the link to your CSS?

Comment: Thanks for all your confirmations! Kevin, your idea of "an issue" put me on the right track - the CSS itself (or better: a comment that was not a comment) was the issue. Case closed! Kevin, if you want to post your suggestion as an Answer, I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand slightly on what I said in my comment.

It should work as is, I copied and pasted your code to test it, and it did work, maybe there is an issue with the link to your CSS?

On top of that, while being more specific will allow you to overwrite CSS, as long as you have an equal amount of specificity, it will still work.

```
body {
  background: blue;
}

body {
  background: red;
}

/* background is red */
```

The same applied when overwriting Bootstrap's stuff, just ensure you have an equal amount of specificity and you're golden.

To make you're life easier, you can also make your selector a lot shorter.

```
div[class^='col'] {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

This uses an attribute selector, so all divs that start with an attribute of `col`. If you use just the `=`, it will only work for exact matches, the `^=` means all of them that start with that.